# Which of the following ways is more optimized?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, query-optimization

I am using Entity Framework 4 and asp.net mvc 3.I am writing a system to sign up and write some posts and vote up other's posts.I want to save the posts that is voted up by a person.There may be thousands of people and thousands of posts that have been voted up by each of them.Now I have 2 questions:

1-Can I create tables with entity framework?

2-Which one is better?Having a table named `Like` with millions of records or create a tabel name `UserLike` for each person to save his vote ups in that?

Comment: Creating thousands of tables for "*thousands of people"* sounds so crazy to me, I wouldn't even think about it. If your database system can handle such an amount of tables in a performant way, it can also handle a single table with millions of records (which is the straight-forward and less complicated way).

Comment: Also having multiple tables is going to cause design issues when you want to select the likes of user X. Selecting from a constant `Like` table is easier than trying to figure out which one to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont do a table by user, it's kind of crazy!

Just with these three tables : `User`, `Post` and `Like` you should be alright.